# Can I use a Terminal command to switch to a specific space in OS X 10.6?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, osx-spaces, expose

Is there any terminal command I can use to switch directly to a space  in OS X 10.6 ?

Something like:

```
spaces switch 2
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have assigned keyboard shortcuts for switching between Spaces in *System Preferences*, you can trigger them using AppleScript:

> `osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to key code 124 using control down'`

This will effectively press `Control-Right`. `Left` is 123, `Up` is 126, and `Down` is 125.

These are the key codes for the number keys:

> 1 `18`
>   2 `19`
>   3 `20`
>   4 `21`
>   5 `23`
>   6 `22`
>   7 `26`
>   8 `28`
>   9 `25`
>   0 `29`

---

Just assign an alias to that `osascript` call or wrap it in a shell function.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I guess you don't know of a way to do it other than the old "have applescript press the keys for me" method then?

Comment: @cwd I didn't find anything. Given the UI requirement and the default assignable shortcuts it's likely not supported because it's of limited usefulness. But wait a few days, maybe Lri or slhck or someone else has an idea.

Comment: Thanks, I gave you an upvote. Take a look at this one too when you have a chance: http://superuser.com/questions/368154/

Answer (score 2):

From @Daniel's answer a quick zsh command to switch to a numbered desktop accessible through ctrl + desktopnumber.

```
switchdesktop() {
    typeset -A desktophash
    desktophash[0]=29
    desktophash[1]=18
    desktophash[2]=19
    desktophash[3]=20
    desktophash[4]=21
    desktophash[5]=23
    desktophash[6]=22
    desktophash[7]=26
    desktophash[8]=28
    desktophash[9]=25
    desktopkey=${desktophash[$1]}
    osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to key code $desktopkey using control down"
}
alias switchdesktop=switchdesktop
```

usage: `switchdesktop 5`