# How can I sort a folder in OS X Lion without having to group files as done with "Arrange By"?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, finder, sorting

I'm sorry to say there are several things I liked better in Snow Leopard. Sorting files in Finder is one of those things.

If I "Arrange By" -> "None" it does not group items and it looks like 10.6. I like this. I can still click on the bar to sort by name, etc., and it looks fine and does not group:

[image]

However, if I select "Arrange By" and choose another option, the folder starts looking different (column headers) and it starts grouping things:

[image]

1. I don't want them grouped.
2. I want to use the old keyboard shortcuts, I think they were alt+1 - alt+6 to change the sort order. Also, pressing the keyboard shortcut again would toggle the sort order from ascending to descending.

How can I make my life better on Lion? Applescript would be an acceptable solution, but maybe editing the default plist file could also work or unlock some hidden option.

Comment: @DanielBeck - haha, thanks for the upvote. Losing this functionality reminded me of transitioning from XP to Vista and no longer being able to easily do a view by list with `alt-v-l` or sort by date with `alt-o-d` - I really hope there is a workaround.

Comment: The previous keyboard shortcuts were repurposed. `Ctrl-Cmd-N` sorted by the column, instead of *arranging*.

Comment: I really hate the grouping and so glad to see a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to press `Ctrl-Opt-Cmd-Number` instead of `Ctrl-Cmd-Number`.

To get the *sorting* (instead of *arranging*) menu items, hold down `Option`. The implemented the *Sort by/Arange by* submenu somewhat oddly though, so pressing Option while it's already visible won't change the menu items.

---

[image]

Comment: Awesome. I wondered why I didn't have the "Sort by" in the menu. Yes, holding option was the trick! Thanks!

Comment: Any way to press it more than once and have it toggle ascending / descending?